# Is this a Fuchsian group?

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, isometry, combinatorial-group-theory

Consider the matrices in $\textit{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$T= \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$
and
$S= \left(\begin{matrix} 4 & 0\\
0 & 1/4
\end{matrix}\right)$. Then is the subgroup generated by $T$ and $S$ a Fuchsian group?

I would be happy with hints. I was trying to make some diagrams to understand how the translations and dilations are working, but couldn't arrive at anything concrete. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of elements are they?

Comment: I said translations and dilations. Parabolic and hyperbolic.

Comment: Do you know anything about the common fixed point (in infinite boundary) in a fuchsian group?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: What are the fixed point of T and S?

Comment: I'm not giving you the answer. I'm just giving you a few hints ( key words) so that you can get the answer by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try to compute the isometry $S^{-n}TS^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then doing the product of the matrices involved, we obtain
$S^{-n}TS^n = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 4^{-2n} \\
                                    0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$. Now, as $n\to\infty$, this goes to the identity matrix. Thus the group generated by $T$ and $S$ is not discrete. Hence, it is $\textit{not}$ a Fuchsian group.